# How to fill empty index or empty row based on another column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
             Date                Cities       Random_Number
Country
US           2020-01-01          LA           100
             2020-01-03          LA           150
UK           2020-01-01          Ldn          125
             2020-01-03          Birmingham   135
```

My desired data frame:

```
             Date                Cities       Random_Number
Country
US           2020-01-01          LA           100
US           2020-01-03          LA           150
UK           2020-01-01          Ldn          125
UK           2020-01-03          Birmingham   135
```

My aim is to have empty index row to be filled. Many thanks.

Comment: do `df.reset_index()`

Comment: did that, but didnt work.

Comment: Waht is `print (df.index)` in first `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Index(['US','','UK','']),dtype = 'object',name = 'Country'..

Comment: Try - df.reset_index().set_index('Country')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [there are empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60545490/how-to-fill-empty-index-or-empty-row-based-on-another-column-value/60545628#comment107112275_60545490) first convert them to missing values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then forward filling missing values by `ffill`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Country        Date      Cities  Random_Number
0      US  2020-01-01          LA            100
1          2020-01-03          LA            150
2      UK  2020-01-01         Ldn            125
3          2020-01-03  Birmingham            135

df['Country'] = df['Country'].mask(df['Country'] == '').ffill()
print (df)
  Country        Date      Cities  Random_Number
0      US  2020-01-01          LA            100
1      US  2020-01-03          LA            150
2      UK  2020-01-01         Ldn            125
3      UK  2020-01-03  Birmingham            135
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
data.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Got your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `df.head(4)` to 'ungroup' the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['US', '2020-01-01', 'LA', 100],
                   ['US', '2020-01-03', 'LA', 150],
                   ['UK', '2020-01-01', 'Ldn', 125],
                   ['UK', '2020-01-03', 'Birmingham', 135]],
                  columns=['Country', 'Date', 'Cities', 'Random_Number']).groupby('Country')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
             Date                Cities       Random_Number
Country
US           2020-01-01          LA           100
             2020-01-03          LA           150
UK           2020-01-01          Ldn          125
             2020-01-03          Birmingham   135
```

Ungroup:

```
print(df.head(4))
```

Result:

```
  Country        Date      Cities  Random_Number
0      US  2020-01-01          LA            100
1      US  2020-01-03          LA            150
2      UK  2020-01-01         Ldn            125
3      UK  2020-01-03  Birmingham            135
```